# R Group option not working when creating barplot on separate sheet to data using openxlsx2 and mschart

Tags: r, openxlsx

I need to create a bar chart in Excel on a separate sheet to the data. The only way I have managed to do this is by adding the data to the workbook object then referencing that as the data source for the chart. However, when I do it this way the group argument in ms_barchart function does not appear to work. See example below. If I create the chart directly from the data frame the chart and a data table are added to the same sheet and the group by argument works. I can't find a function to move the chart to a new sheet after its added through  wb_add_mschart

```
library(openxlsx2)
library(mschart)

## Create Workbook object and add worksheets
wbTest <-  wb_workbook()

wbTest <- wbTest %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("add_mschart - wb_data") %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("Chart1") %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("Chart2") %>% 
  wb_add_data(x = browser_data, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "A1")

##Read data from workbook object
dat <- wb_data(wbTest, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "A1:C19")

##Create chart from dataframe
chart_01 <- ms_barchart(
  data = browser_data, x = "browser",
  y = "value", group = "serie"
)

##Create chart using same data but read from workbook object
chart_02 <- ms_barchart(
  data = dat, x = "browser",
  y = "value", group = "serie"
)

## add charts to workbook
wbTest <- wbTest %>%
  wb_add_mschart(sheet = "chart1", dim = "H20", graph = chart_01) %>% 
  wb_add_mschart(sheet = "chart2", graph = chart_02)

## save workbook
wb_save(wbTest, file = "ChartTest2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see in the top corner of the sheet `Chart1` is what is used by `mschart` for the data creation. And `mschart` on it's own uses some opinionated data aggregation. If you want to recreate the plot, we can use something like this (tested it with Arch Linux and LibreOffice). I've added a `Chart3` sheet and the data in wide format to the data sheet.

In theory it should be fairly easy to write the data to a different sheet, I just never saw the need, because I do not like the under the hood `mschart` data aggregation in the first place.

```r
library(openxlsx2)
library(mschart)

## Create Workbook object and add worksheets
wbTest <-  wb_workbook()

prep_data <- browser_data %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = serie)

wbTest <- wbTest %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("add_mschart - wb_data") %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("Chart1") %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("Chart2") %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet("Chart3") %>% 
  wb_add_data(x = browser_data, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "A1") %>% 
  wb_add_data(x = prep_data, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "E1")

##Read data from workbook object
dat <- wb_data(wbTest, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "A1:C19")
tab <- wb_data(wbTest, sheet = "add_mschart - wb_data", dims = "E1:H7")

##Create chart from dataframe
chart_01 <- ms_barchart(
  data = browser_data, x = "browser",
  y = "value", group = "serie"
)

##Create chart using same data but read from workbook object
chart_02 <- ms_barchart(
  data = dat, x = "browser",
  y = "value", group = "serie"
)

##Create chart using same data but read from workbook object
chart_03 <- ms_barchart(
  data = tab, x = "browser",
  y = c("serie1", "serie2", "serie3") 
) %>% 
  chart_labels(ylab = "value")

## add charts to workbook
wbTest <- wbTest %>%
  wb_add_mschart(sheet = "chart1", dim = "H20", graph = chart_01) %>% 
  wb_add_mschart(sheet = "chart2", graph = chart_02) %>% 
  wb_add_mschart(sheet = "chart3", graph = chart_03)

if (interactive())
  wbTest %>% wb_open()
```